# Laravel, not displayed image from public folder

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with displaing images from public directory:

```
<img src="{{asset('public/front/images')}}/index/logo.jpg">
```

Image looks like this. [image]

from another folders images are displaed correctly

```
<img src="{{url('/')}}/images/banner1.jpg" >
```

Comment: Inspect the image using browser debugger and check what is path there?

Comment: may be path missing check it out once...and follow the comment of @ParthVora

Comment: Use public_path() to get path upto public

Comment: anyone on this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel has some rewrite rules to rewrite you url path. The static files may not be accessed due to following reasons:
1. Check the permission of your folders, "chmod -R 777 folder" in Linux or authenticate the permission to anyone for the folder in Windows, then try again.
2. Check the web server configure if it restrcits the folder to be accessed.
3. Check your route if there is any route/resource/route::group has the same name with the folder.

By the way, you can put your static files in another folder which is out of the base_path() in Laravel, then set a alias in the web server to let it be accessed. In case, this method makes the structure more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('front/images/index/logo.jpg'); }}">
```

You don't need to use **public** prefix with asset().

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this, If your image is in public folder

```
<img src="{{url('images/banner1.jpg')}}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check this one

```html
<html>
<body>
  <img src="{{ URL::asset('/front/images/index/logo.jpg') }}" />
</body>
</html>
```